# Is omission of the auxiliary verb 'have been" possible here?

Tags: grammar

This is my web application, which deals with different courses for people to acquire some new skills, etc. And after they completed all the courses there appears such an inscription as "Congratulations, all courses completed!". So the question is, is it possible to say so as in the above mentioned phrase or I need to say "Congratulations, all courses have been completed!". Or if you want to hide some courses you've already passed there is a button with an inscription "Hide courses passed". Are these variants correct from the point of grammar and is understandable to native speakers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not grammatical in ordinary prose.

But an abbreviated form, omitting many articles and auxiliaries, is common in headlines, titles, notices, and interaction messages. (See [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)). Your phrase is fine in that context.